# Predicitve back with Compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-13, jetpack-compose-navigation

According to the [Android Developer docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/predictive-back) it is possible to implement custom animations for the [predictive back gesture](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture). I got it to work on an example similar to the one they present in [their docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/predictive-back#androidx-transitions) with the Transition APIs.

However, I would like to implement a similar gradular transition based on the back progress for the [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) in Jetpack Compose.

How would I do so? I can't find any documentation on being able to control the progress of the transition between different navigation destinations.

Here's an example of my `NavHost`:

```
NavHost(navController = pageNavController!!, startDestination = "home"){
    composable(
    route = "home",
    enterTransition = { 
        navEnterTransition(
            direction = DIRECTION_LEFT, 
            orientation = orientation) },
    exitTransition = { 
        navExitTransition(
            direction = DIRECTION_LEFT, 
            orientation = orientation) },
        content = { HomePage() }
    )
    composable(
        route = "settings",
        enterTransition = { navEnterTransition(
            direction = getNavEnterDirection(initialState.destination),
            orientation = orientation) },
        exitTransition = { navExitTransition(
            direction = getNavExitDirection(initialState.destination),
            orientation = orientation) },
        content = { SettingsPage() }
    )
}
```

Is there a way to implement the custom predictive back gestures with this navigation approach?

If not, are there other approaches that might work?

---

#### Edit

As [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136215558?noredirect=1) pointed out, this is not supported yet.

However, I was able to somewhat get it to work using the [Pager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/pager) and some complicated custom navigation and modifiers. This worked and incorporated the predictive back gesture but was very unstable and had some bugs so I decided against and I will just wait for official support.

Comment: This isn't supported yet, but will be automatic in the future. You can track progress in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273554698).